# How to get rid of Back to Messenger after sharing link thru messenger sharing dialog

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently here's my code to open the sharing dialog to share a link thru messenger:

```
let invitationLink = NSURL(string:"http://somelink.com")

        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb-messenger-api://")!)){

            let share  = FBSDKMessageDialog()

            share.shareContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()

            share.delegate = self
            share.shareContent.contentURL = invitationLink

            share.show()
        }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

And I'm handling the response as well thru FBSDKSharingDelegate on my view controller

By doing so, the app opens Messenger and it seems like when the messenger sharing is done or cancelled, I still have "Back to Messenger" like if Messenger app was the originator ... I would have expected not to see that "Back to Messenger" button after closing the sharing dialog.. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you open your apps stack do you see the facebook messenger?

Comment: Yes Messenger appears in stack

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to `AppDelegate`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}
```